# Can't get along with the @font-face rule

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I have a problem importing a font to my CSS file, and I can't understand the problem.

The code:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Reg';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Reg'), url(carmelit.ttf) format('ttf');
}

body{
    font-family: 'Reg';     
}
```

This is not working, and not because I'm overriding it later on. The file "carmelit.ttf" is in the same folder as the CSS file.

Comment: May I know which browser you tested it? see cross browser font face solution https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

Comment: use http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator to generate cross browser @font-face

Answer (score 0):

`format('ttf')` should be `format('truetype')`

You can also remove the `local` info unless you're supporting ancient versions of IE.

Answer (score 0):

You should also try like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: myFirstFont;
    src: url(sansation_light.woff);
}

div {
    font-family: myFirstFont;
}
```